# C++ delete problems dynamically allocated memory

Tags: c++, memory

I have some issues about this code:

1) Why the output returns trash if I delete the first cell ?

```
int b = 1025;
char *v = new char[sizeof(int)];
memcpy(v,&b,sizeof(int));

char *pp = (char*)v;    
++pp;

delete v; // is equal delete &v[0]

cout<<"salida"<<*pp;
```

2) How to delete dynamically allocated memory when i have void* ...

```
void *pv = v;
```

is correct

```
delete pv;
```

or

```
delete [](char*) pv;
```

Comment: 1. Undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A call to `new[]` needs to be matched by a call to `delete[]` on the same memory address and using the same pointer type.

A call to `new` needs to be matched by a call to `delete` on the same memory address and using the same pointer type.

If you mix things up, then you're invoking undefined behavior and will eventually have problems.

Maybe you'll occasionally be "lucky" and get away with it in certain simple circumstances because of how certain compilers have implemented dynamically allocated memory, but it's still a bad idea and could break at any time. If you try this with a class type which has a destructor, then one common consequence is that the destructor will not be properly run on some or all of the instances. But of course there are other possibilities, such as heap corruption.

So the result of a `new char[]` statement *must* be deallocated by a `delete[]` statement on a pointer of type `char*`.

Comment: thanks for responde so delete [](char*) pv; is correct ?

Comment: @Pepe Yes, if you really need to have a void pointer in there, then using that cast is the correct way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

i think what you are trying to do is deallocating the dynamically allocated memory..
first a pointer is always size of an int.

It only handles data locations(references).
A char pointer can store the address of a char type variable.

A void pointer can store the address of any data type.

so delete option works for both type of data types.

it simply deallocate the space and make it available on heap

Answer (score 0):

What exactly are you trying to delete, the `char *v` or `void *pv`?

If you want to delete `char *v`,

`delete[] v;
v = NULL; // v still exists, but it's a dangling pointer now, so we set it to NULL (or 0)`

Usually when you want to `delete` something, it has to be paired with `new`. So I think if you want to delete `void *pv`, you have to initialize the void pointer to `new` like this:

`void** pv = new(void*); // Create a void pointer using new
pv = (char *)v;
delete pv;`

Comment: thanks for response but in the second i want to delete void *pv

Comment: i have problems with the size because a void* point to first byte but i want to delete all space allocated.

Answer (score 0):

You can't delete just one element of a dynamically-allocated array.  If you allocate an array with `new[]`, you can only delete the entire array, and you must use `delete[]`, not `delete`.

Doing

```
char *v = new char[sizeof(int)];
```

and then

```
delete v;
```

invokes undefined behavior.  You need to do `delete[] v`, and then you can no longer use `pp` because it points to something that's been deleted.